# Shnayim Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-two?

### ?שנים ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 322.

People, let's ramp up our game and conquer this number! Don't just lie down on the job and resort to lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred twenty-one entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: It seems like this series is drying up at 322, which is the Gematria of היבשה

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hadad ben Bedad who fought with Midyan in the field of Moav during the war of Midyan and Moav occurred in the year 322 of the third thousand (2322)

Source: Seder Hadoros

Answer (score 5):

Three hundred twenty two are the years of the Kings of Judah after Jehoshaphat's alliance to Ahab and/or the birth of Ahazia from that alliance.

From the beginning of his reign until the destruction is 332 years and 6 months, adding up the reigns of all the Kings with no coregencies. Jehoshaphat reigned 25 years, then Jehoram reigned 8, then Ahaziah came to power at 22 years of age. If you say that Ahaziah was a full 22 years old, and into his 23rd year, that would make him fourteen going on 15 when Jehoram came to power, which would mean that he was born from the alliance around 10 years into Jehoshaphat's reign, leaving around 322 years before the temple's destruction.

(If you say he was born right after the alliance, then the alliance itself can be included).